# remove validation for Add to cart

Tags: magento-1.9

user can upload image and text on [product image](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html),  after that user muct click on custom button "**save design**" , after that only **onclick "Add to cart"** button will add item to cart. but we want to remove that validation for add to cart button.

What i need is Once user upload image or text and if user click on "Add to cart", it should add item to cart.

We have [below code](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/js/aitoc/aitcg/Aitcg/View/Abstract.js) for "**save design**"

```
_getControlPanelHtml: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            return '<div id="aitcg-control-panel">' +
                '<button id="submit-editorApply-{{rand}}" >SAVE DESIGN</button>' +
                '<button >Reset</button>' +
                '</div>';
        }
        return '';
    },


    initObservers: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            $('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this));
            $('submit-editorReset-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitReset.bindAsEventListener(this));
        }
    },

    submitApply: function(event)
    {
        Event.stop(event);
        this.option.apply();
    },
```

I tried below code , now "Add to cart" is working without clicking "save design", but **after clicking "save design", than "Add to cart" is not working.**

```
<script>

initObservers: function()
    {
        if (this.config.editorEnabled) {
            $('submit-editorApply-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitApply.bindAsEventListener(this));
            $('submit-editorReset-' + this.config.rand).observe('click', this.submitReset.bindAsEventListener(this));

            var buttonCart = $$('.btn-cart')[0];
            buttonCart.removeAttribute('onclick');
            buttonCart.observe('click', this.addToCart.bindAsEventListener(this));
            console.log(buttonCart);
        }
    },

    addToCart: function(event)
    {
        Event.stop(event);
        this.submitApply(event);

        productAddToCartForm.submit(this)
    },
```

phtml : https://pastebin.com/xeWKNUs4 , script : https://pastebin.com/p8UU7zQ1

[image]

Comment: Remove this class validation-passed in your Add to cart button

Comment: @Kothari i am not getting, can you tell what line of code i need to remove ?

Comment: I don't know line number open you site inspect element your Add to cart there you add one more class validation-passed so you need to remove that

Comment: @Kothari i found that class in file `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml` i renamed the class to `validation-passed1` still its not working for me......

Comment: On click Add to cart this class is adding so you have to find how this class added and then remove

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check function submit of Add to Cart button in 
**...\app\design\frontend......\template\catalog\product\view.phtml**

Check this script:

```
productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
        if (this.validator.validate()) {
            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
               form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }
        }
    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

Change to

```
productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {

            var form = this.form;
            var oldUrl = form.action;

            if (url) {
               form.action = url;
            }
            var e = null;
            try {
                this.form.submit();
            } catch (e) {
            }
            this.form.action = oldUrl;
            if (e) {
                throw e;
            }

            if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                button.disabled = true;
            }

    }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you please tell what code changes i need to do to get solution.....

Comment: I have edited the answer. You can try to change like that.

Comment: Thanks, i updated your code , but still i am facing same issue in [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html#)

Comment: Are you sure you update correct template? http://prntscr.com/esm8l1

Comment: I can see the script not change

Comment: sorry for that, let me check......

Comment: means if we upload any image or text and click on `save design` and than `add to cart` , we can see custom image under `Recently added items or in cart page` , but if we click directly on `add to cart`, than its not displaying those custom images, instead its showing normal regular product image....

Comment: in image : http://prnt.sc/esmbvn , you can see in 1st product, i clicked on `save design` and than `add to cart`, so its displaying custom image. but in 2nd product, we can see normal product image, because we clicked directly on `add to cart`.....